# In what order do weapons fire?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

If I have three weapons fully charged, pause the game and set them to target specific systems and then unpause, do the fire in the order I marked my targets?

The reason I'm asking is that it can be rather crucial when taking down shields. I want weapon 1 to take down the shield and weapons 2 and 3 to pass through. I do not want all the shots stopped by the shield. I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They will all fire at the same time. However, you can change the location of the weapon by changing the weapon slot it is equipped in. The ones at the front of your ship... 
[image]

...will have less distance to travel. (Most of the time, it works 4/5 times for me).

However, weapon speed is also a factor; when you compare them, ion and flak weapons are around the same speed, and lasers are almost two times that speed.

Source:http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Weapons/Tables

Comment: It also depends on the speed of the projectiles, doesn't it?

Comment: Which essentially means that I might have to pause and unpause between each shot if I want to reach maximum efficieny?

Comment: @sepp2k I didn't even know that was a thing.

Comment: @Sandokan You could change the order of your weapons, but that could cause a problem if your weapon system is hit and your essential weapons are taken offline.

Comment: Laser-based weapons have pretty much the same projectile speed. And there may be ships where the weapon sequence doesn't map with position. To obtain maximum efficiency, I tend to phase shots, mainly because some lasers that do double damage to hulls would be squandered in shields.

Comment: @ChargingPun That's in the answer.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard Thanks for the bit about weapon position. I added it, but if I've interpreted it wrong, feel free to change it.

Comment: Sepp2k had a point about speed. Lasers and missiles travel significantly faster than ions and flak.

Comment: @Studoku Do you have a link to any info on that?

Comment: @peper757 Only in-game experience.

Comment: @peper757 I haven't played the game in a while, so the bit about weapon position might be slightly off. I however managed to find a chart with some weapons' speed [here](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Weapons/Tables) if it might be of help.

Comment: In addition to what Studoku said, beam weapons are also much faster (instantaneous?) than anything else.

Comment: @sepp2k I left that out because I didn't see anything about in the table that's linked.

Answer (score 12):

All of your weapons will *start* firing at the same time if you trigger them at the same time. Each weapon will *arrive* depending on the speed of the projectile and the firing delay of the weapon. The arrival time of projectiles is modified *very* slightly depending on where it is on your ship: weapons mounted at the bow will arrive faster than weapons mounted on the wings, because they have slightly less distance to traverse.

According to the [weapons table on the wiki](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Weapons/Tables), the projectile-based weapons fire at roughly two speeds: laser weapons are fast, and ion and flak weapons move at a little over half that speed. Beam weapons, on the other hand, are nigh-instantaneous: they hit at the same time they fire. Bombs have a specific delay: after being fired, there's a short time until the bomb appears on the ship, and then another delay before it explodes.

Imagine you have the following weapons on your ship (ignoring, for the moment, that this configuration is impossible):

- Pike Beam (1 damage beam weapon)
- Ion Bomb (4 damage ion bomb)
- A Heavy Laser I (1 damage to shields, 2 damage to hull/system)
- A Flak Gun I (3 damage, with poor aim)
- A Heavy Pierce I (2 damage, ignores 1 shield)
- A Burst Laser I (2 shots of 1 damage each)
- A Hermes Missile (3 damage)

Your opponent has level 3 shields: they will avoid 3 shots of damage, and the shield system has 6 health (though it will cease generating any shield once it has taken 5 damage).

In a perfect world, you want the shots to arrive in the following order:

1. Ion Bomb on the pilot to prevent evasion on everything else (For the sake of this example, assume it hits.)
2. Hermes Missile on the shields
3. Heavy Pierce I on the shields, ignoring the last shield and reducing the shields to 0
4. Everything else, to do unspeakable damage to whatever's left

You trigger the weapons in the following order, unpausing briefly between each shot:

1. Ion Bomb
2. Hermes Missile and Flak Gun I (just after the Ion Bomb arrives, to guarantee that the Ion Bomb will explode before the Missile can arrive and be dodged). The Flak Gun I would normally hit the shields, but flak projectiles are slow and will get there after the shields are down from the Heavy Pierce I in a moment.
3. Heavy Pierce I, after the Missile leaves your ship but before it arrives. You must damage the shields before the Heavy Pierce shot even touches the shields.
4. Burst Laser I and Heavy Laser I, after the Heavy Pierce I leaves your ship but before it arrives. You must damage the shields before the laser shots even touch the shields.
5. Pike Beam, only after you see the shields go down. The beam will hit nigh-instantly.